# modifying working directory and staging area temporarily in git pre-commit hook

Tags: git, bash, githooks

I'm using an an approach similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5518349/using-git-to-track-mysql-schema-some-questions) to use a pre-commit hook to track changes to my database schema (as well as a few metadata-ish tables).

I like to try to keep my commits clean so I want to be loudly warned in the commit message when there are automatic changes being staged/committed. Here are my `pre-commit` and `pre-commit-msg` hooks:

.git/hooks/pre-commit

```bash
#!/bin/sh

# Save user changes to db/ (if any)
git diff --quiet db/
user_dirty=$?
[[ $user_dirty > 0 ]] && git stash save --keep-index

# Regenerate db/ automatically
db/save_schema_and_meta_tables.sh

# Were any automatic changes made? If so, commit them but warn about it
git diff --quiet db/
auto_dirty=$?
if [[ $auto_dirty > 0 ]]; then
    git add db/
    echo "WARNING: automatic changes to db/ added to commit" | tee .git/COMMIT_WARNING
fi

[[ $user_dirty > 0 ]] && git stash pop
exit 0
```

.git/hooks/prepare-commit-msg

```bash
#!/bin/sh
msgf=$1
wf=.git/COMMIT_WARNING
if [ -e $wf ]; then
    msg=$(<$msgf)
    ( cat $wf; echo "$msg" ) > $msgf
    rm -f $wf
fi
```

Here's how it behaves:

1. If I have made changes to `db/` but haven't staged them yet, they are kept in the working tree without disturbing the commit, thanks to `stash save --keep-index` and `stash pop`. Good!
2. However, if I have **staged** changes to `db/` and they are overwritten by the automatic commit, then the user-intended changes are gone after the commit. Bad!

Here's what I would **like** to happen: if there are user-staged changes to `db/` and they don't exactly match the automatic changes, then the whole thing should abort. I'm having a lot of trouble figuring out how to implement this: how can I save the staged changes made by the user, then see if the automatic changes don't match?

Comment: I have not thought about your entire issue here, but you might want to look over http://stackoverflow.com/q/20479794/1256452 where I write about how to use `git stash save --keep-index` in a pre-commit hook, and how to make it mostly-reliable.  In your case I think what you want to do here is make several commits (including the stash ones) and compare them.

Comment: Thanks, @torek. The strategy in your thread is good. Trying to do this with `git stash` tricks is driving me a little crazy. The bug you point out is frustrating too... I've definitely been bit by it as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not pretty, and it's slow, but with some of @torek's suggestions I came up with the following.

1. Check if user has staged changes to the `db/` directory (`user_staged=1` if so)
2. Stash user changes, while preserving the staging area
3. Auto-generate the contents of the `db/` directory
4. Compare the staged version of the `db/` directory to the auto-generated version (`auto_changes=1` if they differ)
5. Restore the user's working directory (modulo [the bug torek identified](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git/234153)), while preserving a copy of the auto-generated version of `db/`
6. Decision:

   - If user-staged and auto-generated `db/` matched, **all is well**
   - If user-staged and auto-generated `db/` didn't match, **abort**
   - If user hadn't staged any changes to `db/` but there are auto-generated changes, stage them and continue, but **warn** about them in the commit message

The `pre-commit` hook code:

```
# Has user staged changes to db/?
git diff --quiet --staged db/
user_staged=$?

# Stash any user changes in the working tree
old_stash=$(git rev-parse -q --verify refs/stash)
git stash save -q --keep-index
new_stash=$(git rev-parse -q --verify refs/stash)
[[ "$old_stash" != "$new_stash" ]] && stashed=1 || stashed=0

# Automatically regenerate db/
db/save_schema_and_meta_tables.sh
cp -a db db_AUTO

# Compare automatically-generated changes to what the user had already staged
git diff --quiet db/
auto_changes=$?

# Restore user's state
[[ $stashed ]] && git reset --hard -q && git stash apply --index -q && git stash drop -q

# abort: if user had staged changes to db/, and automatic changes would overwrite them
# add but warn: automatic changes added, but no user changes to db/
# silent: no user-staged changes, no automatic changes
if (( $auto_changes > 0 )); then
    if (( $user_staged > 0 )); then
        echo "ERROR: automatic changes to db/ conflict with staged changes"
        rm -rf db_AUTO
        exit 1
    else
        rm -rf db/
        mv db_AUTO db
        git add db/
        echo "WARNING: automatic changes to db/ added to commit" | tee .git/COMMIT_WARNING
        exit 0
    fi
else
    rm -rf db_AUTO
fi
```

Comment: BTW, one of my favorite sh-script tricks is to set a variable to either `true` or `false` (rather than 1 or 0) and then use `$var && iftrue_action`, etc.  `tf() { $@ && echo true || echo false; }  user_staged=$(tf diff --quiet --staged db/)` for instance.

Comment: Clever! My version can certainly use some cleanup/simplification. My first focus was getting it to work at all without borking the commits and working tree silently :-).

Comment: Yes, I've been burned before by the "optimize first, get working later" apprach :-)